# How to fix a java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion

My teacher makes us do these error fixing assignments, and I just can't fix this one. That's why I came here. I want to ask for one favor and a few questions

Questions: What does the error message mean in detail(I just want to know for my own curiosity), Why does it occur specifically using my code, How can I fix it

Favor: Can u please fix my code, Sorry if this seems like a way to get an answer but I'm a bit lost.

Here's the code

```
public class Recursion
        {
         public static void indifferent( int x, int y )
          {

            System.out.print( x );
              indifferent( x - 1, y + 2 );
               System.out.print( y );

        }
     }

       public class RecursionDriver//-the driver class
        {
          public static void main( String [] args )
          {

             Recursion.indifferent( 7, -1 );

          }
        }
```

Comment: What is `Recursion.indifferent()` supposed to do? Currently he function does infinite recursion and the stack will ran out, which is what the error message means.

Comment: The answer to your question "Can you fix my code" is yes I can.  But I won't.  This is not a "do my homework for me" site.

Comment: Well I'm not completely sure what indifferent means because this is what my teacher told us to put as the name for the class(she said its meaningless and told us to ignore it)

Comment: Possible fix: `public static void indifferent( int x, int y ) {}` The name is meaningless, so let's make the method itself meaningless!

Comment: @MikeCAT - that's an incorrect fix.  The fixed version will produce different output to the original one.  Lets assume that the lecturer has actually set a homework task that has a point to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the code it should be obvious that it can never terminate.  Every call to `indifferent` makes another call to `indifferent`.  Unconditionally.

The `StackOverflowError` happens because the nested calls have gotten too deep.  Java method calls use a stack to hold local variables (and the return address, and other stuff).  The stack has a fixed size.  If you have too many nested calls, the stack overflows.

How to fix it?  Rewrite the code to do what it is currently doing, but *without* using recursion.

But first you need to understand what it is doing.  How do you do that?  Well ... basically ... you read the code.

> Well I'm not completely sure what indifferent means because this is what my teacher told us to put as the name for the class(she said its meaningless and told us to ignore it)

Yup.  Ignore the name, and read what the code actually does.  If you can't figure it out ... then "hand execute" it using a pencil and paper.

Comment: For recursion, do we always need a base case? why?  or why not? I wanted to know because I asked my teacher via email and she mentioned that a base case was important, but i don't understand why, is it to prevent this exact error?

Comment: If there is no base case, then the recursion will continue forever.  I guess that makes it important ... doesn't it.  Hint: Google for "recursion base case".

Answer (score 0):

In recursion you try to divide your problem in sub problems and try to compute the result. Hence, in recursion you always need to have a base case. Base case in the final depth of your recursion. Once you reach the base case you start coming out of the recursion and get you final answer.

In your code:

```
public static void indifferent( int x, int y )
{
      System.out.print( x );
      indifferent( x - 1, y + 2 );
      System.out.print( y );
}
```

You do not have a base case, do your code just keeps going deep in recursion.

```
public static void indifferent( int x, int y )
    {
          if(x == 1) //example of a base case
              return;
          System.out.print( x );
          indifferent( x - 1, y + 2 );
          System.out.print( y );
    }
```